# Get native size of iPhone (6, 6 Plus, 5 etc) even when only running in zoomed mode (iPhone 5 mode)

Tags: ios, iphone

An iPhone 6 Plus running in zoomed mode (ie not supporting iPhone 6 Plus by a native launch image) returns a screen size of 320x568 points. I'd like to get the native point size at runtime of the current device. Which for iPhone 6 Plus should be 414x736 points. The app must run in zoomed mode (iPhone 5ish size).

Let's take that again:

1. Create an iPhone app only natively supporting iPhone 5 (and 4...)
2. Launching the app with an iPhone 6 Plus, we look at `UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size` and it will be 320x568.
3. We want to achieve the native size of iPhone 6 Plus (once again, without adding launch image for iPhone 6 Plus to the app). This is where I'm stuck.

There is `UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeBounds.size`, however it will return the size in pixels which will be something like `834.78260869565224, 1481.7391304347827`. Interesting numbers, but if we divide those by the `UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeScale`, we will get 320x568.

Comment: Please read the question again, I noted at least three times that the app must run in zoomed mode.

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: Sure. (long pause). I need to save native sized wallpapers to the device's camera roll, and in order to get a full sized context I need to know the target device's size.

Comment: Not judging, just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are asking how to get the screen size.

screen size can be obtained from

```
CGSize screenSize = [[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] size];
```

This will return your main screen size. Sorry if I am mistaken.